# How to get Service_key and the corresponding function call interface from the Samba source TGS_REP part

Tags: authentication, kerberos

**1, My existing configuration environment are** as follows: (1), Server_side, Redhat5.5 Enterprise with samba4.0.0 installed, Ip Address: 5.5.5.149; domain name: EXAMPLE.COM; (2), Client_side: windows Server 2003, Ip address: 5.5.5.45, host name: SMB1; I've followed http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO configuration is successful, that is the server-side is configurated as AD DC. Now I can achieved that the client(SMB1) join to the domain EXAMPLE.COM. In the process of SMB1 joining the EXAMPLE.COM, the kerberos authentication is occuring, At the same time, I captured AS_REQ, AS_REP, TGS_REQ and TGS_REP packets through Wireshark tool.

**2, My goal is** find the corresponding function call interface of Sevice_key in the source Samba from the Redhat5.5 server-side. From reading the kerberos related documentation, I learned that the Service_key is exists in TGS_REP request packet, which used for access the server_side in the KRB_AP_REQ.

**3、My Current Progress** is that I have been found the call stacks of AS_REQ and TGS_REQ through single step debugging of gdb tool and setting the gdb level with 10. The call stacks are as follows:

AS_REP call stack is:

**#0./source4/heimdal/kdc/kerberos5.c:1032 #1../source4/heimdal/kdc/process.c:70 #2./source4/heimdal/kdc/process.c:242 #3../source4/kdc/kdc.c:161 #4../source4/kdc/kdc.c:519 #5../lib/tevent/tevent_req.c:101 .........**

TGS_REP call stack is:

#0 ../source4/heimdal/kdc/krb5tgs.c:2355 　　#1../source4/heimdal/kdc/process.c:97 #2../source4/heimdal/kdc/process.c:242 #3../source4/kdc/kdc.c:161 　　#4../source4/kdc/kdc.c:519 　　#5 ../lib/tevent/tevent_req.c:101 .........

Even so, the code is huge and very hard to learn because it related with encryption. My goal has not yet reached

**4, My urgent problems** can be described: The related functions of AS_REQ, AS_REP, TGS_REQ,and TGS_REP packets are more difficult to understand, can you give a detailed explanation?

Firstly, What are the corresponding function interface with AS_REQ, AS_REP, TGS_REQ,and TGS_REP? In particular, the relevant parts with Service_key of TGS_REP?

Secondly, The call logical relationship of above packets?

Thirdly, Specifically, as I am not very clear several functions

1)/source4/heimdal/kdc/kerberos5.c:956 _kdc_as_rep();

2) /source4/heimdal/kdc/krb5tgs.c:2288 _kdc_tgs_rep();

3) /source4/heimdal/kdc/process.c:64 decode_AS_REQ() has no definition.

Please provide some materials such as links to me if possible. Any help would be appreciated sincerely.